# Do I have to visit every biome variation to earn the "Adventuring Time" advancement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I went on an exploration trip in order to get the Adventuring Time advancement, but I'm not sure whether I should visit all the biomes *and* their variantions in order to get it. (e.g. If I visit Jungle, should I also visit Jungle M?).
**So, do I have to also visit the biomes' variations in order to get Adventuring Time?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog states that there are 36 biomes in total that need to be visited to obtain this achievement:

**Forests**
Birch forest, birch forest hills, cold taiga, cold taiga hills, forest, forest hills, jungle, jungle edge, jungle hills, mega taiga, mega taiga hills, roofed forest, swamp land, taiga and taiga hills

**Colder biomes**
Cold beach, frozen river, ice mountains and ice plains.

**Warmer biomes**
Beach, desert, desert hills, mesa, mesa plateau, mesa plateau F, savanna, savanna plateau and stone beach.

**Water biomes**
Deep ocean, ocean and river.

**Other**
Extreme hills, extreme hills +, mushroom island, mushroomislandshore and plains.

The good news is that a lot of these biomes are pretty interconnected anyway, so the list isn't quite so daunting.

Comment: Oh, so the variations don't count. Thanks for confirming me!